# Dúvida com instrução SELECT de uma tabela auto-relacional

Tags: mysql, sql

Olá dev's eu possuo a seguinte tabela cursos(auto-relacional):

`desc cursos;`

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id_curso  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| nome      | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| horas     | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| valor     | float(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| fk_prereq | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Onde `fk_prereq` é a chave estrangeira que faz referência ao id do curso(da própria tabela) que é pre-requisito para o outro, logo se essa coluna assumir um valor `NULL` é porque tal curso não tem pre-requisito.

Tenho alguns dados cadastrados nessa tabela:

`select * from cursos;`

```
+----------+-----------------------+-------+--------+-----------+
| id_curso | nome                  | horas | valor  | fk_prereq |
+----------+-----------------------+-------+--------+-----------+
|        1 | db relacional         |    20 | 400.00 |      NULL |
|        2 | business intelligence |    40 | 800.00 |         1 |
|        3 | relatorios avançados  |    20 | 600.00 |         2 |
|        4 | logica programacao    |    10 | 200.00 |      NULL |
|        5 | ruby                  |    40 | 400.00 |         4 |
+----------+-----------------------+-------+--------+-----------+
```

A minha dúvida é a seguinte, se eu quiser trazer o nome, horas, valor e qual o pre-requisito desse curso, normalmente eu tentaria fazer algo como:

```
select      c.nome
        ,   c.horas
        ,   c.valor
        ,   ifnull(p.nome, '---') as 'pre-requisito' 
from        cursos c 
left join   cursos p on c.id_curso = p.fk_prereq
```

Porém dessa forma a projeção sai errada e o resultado que eu tenho é o seguinte:

```
+-----------------------+-------+--------+-----------------------+
| nome                  | horas | valor  | pre-requisito         |
+-----------------------+-------+--------+-----------------------+
| db relacional         |    20 | 400.00 | business intelligence |
| business intelligence |    40 | 800.00 | relatorios avançados  |
| logica programacao    |    10 | 200.00 | ruby                  |
| relatorios avançados  |    20 | 600.00 | ---                   |
| ruby                  |    40 | 400.00 | ---                   |
+-----------------------+-------+--------+-----------------------+
```

A forma correta seria fazer com essa instrução:

```
select      c.nome
        ,   c.horas
        ,   c.valor
        ,   ifnull(p.nome, '---') as 'pre-requisito' 
from        cursos c 
left join   cursos p on p.id_curso = c.fk_prereq
```

E o resultado seria:

```
+-----------------------+-------+--------+-----------------------+
| nome                  | horas | valor  | pre-requisito         |
+-----------------------+-------+--------+-----------------------+
| db relacional         |    20 | 400.00 | ---                   |
| business intelligence |    40 | 800.00 | db relacional         |
| relatorios avançados  |    20 | 600.00 | business intelligence |
| logica programacao    |    10 | 200.00 | ---                   |
| ruby                  |    40 | 400.00 | logica programacao    |
+-----------------------+-------+--------+-----------------------+
```

Resumindo eu não entendi o porque de uma simples troca de `on c.id_curso = p.fk_prereq` para `on p.id_curso = c.fk_prereq`, mudaria totalmente o resultado esperado, pois em uma tabela que não é auto-relacional se eu fizer da primeira forma que tentei o resultado já sai correto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se ler o artigo [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) no **CodeProject** irá conseguir perceber rápido o porquê do comportamento.

No seu caso seria o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Basicamente, um `LEFT JOIN` permite obter todos os resultados da tabela `A` independentemente de existir ou não associação na tabela `B`, e ao mesmo tempo irá trazer os registos da tabela `B` associados pela chave `fk_prereq` à tabela `A` (devolvendo `NULL` caso contrário).

---

No seu caso acredito que os resultados são diferentes porque do lado esquerdo do `JOIN`, `c.id_curso = p.fk_prereq`, estava a coluna da tabela `A`, o que está a levar ao compilador a ideia de "trocar" as tabelas do `JOIN` precisamente por ser a mesma tabela em ambos os lados, por isso é que quando trocamos as colunas passa a funcionar corretamente.

Comment: Só uma correção: não é do lado esquerdo da comparação, é do lado esquerdo do `join`. O `left join` considera a tabela do lado esquerdo de `from cursos c left join cursos p`, enquanto o `right join` considera a tabela do lado direito, independente da comparação.

Comment: @RonaldoAraújoAlves era isso que queria dizer, mas sim, talvez seja mais correto dizer dessa forma, até para evitar confusões. Obrigado, resposta editada.

Comment: Como assim "trocar" as tabelas do `JOIN` ? Isso ainda ta meio confuso

Comment: @LoneTonberry No relacionamento de `cursos` com `cursos`, o que determina qual tabela representa o curso e qual representa o pré-requisito são os campos linkados. 
Em `p.id_curso = c.fk_prereq` você determina que neste `select` a tabela de alias `c` é o curso principal enquanto a `p` é o curso pré-requisito, como se falasse ao banco: "Quero os registros de `cursos`(alias c), e quero também o nome do `cursos`(alias p) cujos IDs sejam equivalente ao "id de pré-requisito" da minha `cursos`(alias c)"

Comment: Basicamente, se utiliza um `LEFT JOIN` então a tabela que deve estar do lado esquerdo é aquela que pretende ligar (ex.: `left join   cursos p on p.id_curso = c.fk_prereq` onde `p.idcurso` diz respeito à tabela que queremos "juntar" à principal, `cursos c`).